# Insert multiple rows with VALUES meant for different table headers using INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-insert

I don't know if this might be weird to ask this question but I encounter this problem that i tried to figure out. I tried to surf the web for any examples (didn't manage to find any), therefore resulting in me to ask in this forum.

So here's the problem:

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    productName VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    productDescription VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "weight" INTEGER NULL,
    volume INTEGER NULL,
    sizeInformation VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    brandName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (brandName) REFERENCES brand(brandName)
);
```

And I have an `INSERT` statement that looks like this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO product 
    VALUES ("Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial", "Anti-Bacterial", 10, "Dynamo"),
           ("Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial", "Anti-Bacterial", 15, "CloroxLOL");
    COMMIT;
```

So for the 1st `INSERT VALUES` statement (which has the number **10**), I wanted to place that number **10** into `product(weight)`, and for the 2nd `INSERT VALUES` statement (which has the number **15**), I wanted to place that number **15** into `product(volume)`.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: sql server, mysql, oracle...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into product (productName, productDescription, weight, volume, brandName)
values 
    ('Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial', 'Anti-Bacterial', 10, null, 'Dynamo'),
    ('Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial', 'Anti-Bacterial', null, 15, 'CloroxLOL');
```

The idea is to have both columns in the target list, and adjust the list of values with `null` values.

You could also have two separate `inserts` statements, with a different list of target columns (although that's longer to type):

```
insert into product (productName, productDescription, weight, brandName)
values ('Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial', 'Anti-Bacterial', 10, null, 'Dynamo');

insert into product (productName, productDescription, volume, brandName)
values ('Power Gel Laundry Detergent - Anti-Bacterial', 'Anti-Bacterial', null, 15, 'CloroxLOL');
```

Notes:

- always enumerate the list of target columns in a `insert` statement - without a target list, the database expects you to provide values *all columns*; your original query is invalid already (there are 4 values, while your table has 6 columns)
- use single quotes for literal strings rather than double quotes (although some databases support double strings) - this is the SQL standard, that all database support
- avoid double quotes when defining your database objects (tables, columns): they make things more complicated, for usually no benefit

Comment: Yep! Followed your initial solution and it works! Thank you for the detailed solution and the pin-pointing! Appreciate it!